# ReactJS: Locate "Each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have a special question when working with ReactJS.
As already marked in the subject, I have an error called:
"Each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop"

I already know the problem and I know how to fix it.
The only thing what I want to know is how can I locate this error?
I want to know in which file and which line is that error.
I getting some error logs in the console, but it points not to my local files.
I already tested a lot with source maps, but I didn´t have success.

for example is here my error:
[errorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtUTA.png)

and when I click on the following line:

```
at PermissionTable (webpack-internal:///./src/PermissionTable.js:13:26)
```

I will forward to the following screen:
[debugScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRNE8.png)

Is it possible to get somehow the direct location?

Thank you for your support

Greets
Daniel

Comment: convert error to text - it should be available for search engines

Answer (score 0):

### **I don't think there is a `quick` or `direct` way to find it**

From the error message, you would go back to your IDE (VSCode), and search for `PermissionTable` component

Then search for any `map()` function that doesn't return an element with a `key` in it.